# SQL Server update multiple columns with case in single row

Tags: sql

I need help in one query. I use SQL Server 2008.

I have three tables (they are more simple, just for example):

```
create table PriceComponents
( id int,
  summ money,
  svkey1 int,
  comission1 float,
  svkey2 int,
  comission2 float,
  to_key int
  );

create table Comissions
(
id int,
commission float,
svkey int,
to_key int
);

create table Goods
(
to_key int
);
```

and simple data in that tables:

```
insert into Goods values (1), (2), (3);

insert into Comissions values (1, 15, 1, 2), (2, 10, 2, 2), (3, 5, 1, 3);

insert into PriceComponents values (1, 100, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2), (2, 200, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3);
```

And I want to update `PriceComponents` (columns: `comission1` and `comission2`) with that query:

```
update dbo.PriceComponents
set comission1 = case when Comissions.svkey=svkey1 then dbo.Comissions.commission else comission1 end,
    comission2 = case when Comissions.svkey=svkey2 then dbo.Comissions.commission else comission2 end
from dbo.PriceComponents 
left outer join dbo.Goods on dbo.PriceComponents.to_key = dbo.Goods.to_key 
left outer join dbo.Comissions on dbo.Goods.to_key = dbo.Comissions.to_key;
```

So before that query `PriceComponents` has looked like:

```
id  summ    svkey1  comission1  svkey2  comission2  to_key
1   100,00  1       0           2       0           2
2   200,00  1       0           2       0           3
```

and after:

```
id  summ    svkey1  comission1  svkey2  comission2  to_key
1   100,00  1       15          2       0           2
2   200,00  1       5           2       0           3
```

but I expect this result:

```
id  summ    svkey1  comission1  svkey2  comission2  to_key
1   100,00  1       15          2       10          2
2   200,00  1       5           2       0           3
```

I don't really understand where I have an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are `JOIN`ing on `to_key`, but trying to pull from two different rows in `Comissions`, where only one row will match.

The `to_key` value will only match ONE of the `Comissions` rows, which is the first one that is updating `comission1`.  `Comission2` will never match because the `to_key` and `svkey` values won't be correct on the same data row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I execute select query with the same condition: select * from dbo.PriceComponents left outer join dbo.Goods on dbo.PriceComponents.to_key = dbo.Goods.to_key left outer join dbo.Comissions on dbo.Goods.to_key = dbo.Comissions.to_key; I will have three rows. May be I am wrong but I hope that update will use this rows and for one row in PriceComponents I wiil have two updates. And if it is so. How can I complete my task - update all comissions in all rows in PriceComponents?

Comment: You only have one row matching the requirements.  To meet the requirement you probably will need to do two passes on the data